# Singular subject followed by verb without "s"

Tags: verb-agreement

This is the sentence I wish to construct:

> When the show finishes, someone **remind** the ice-cream man to start
>   picking up the garbage.

The verb in question is "remind".  Should it be "remind" or "reminds"?

I have a hunch that it should be "remind".  If so, why is the subject and verb not in agreement?  (Normally "someone reminds" is considered correct.)

Is there a grammatical term to describe this type of usage?  Any reference would be helpful too.

Thanks

Comment: "remind"  in that case is a command in the second person. "[you] remind..."

Comment: If the subject is the understood second person pronoun, what is *someone*?

Comment: So you should use "remind" not "reminds" even though "someone" is technically is a singular noun?  Thank you

Comment: _John – remind me to turn the oven off._ vs _John [always] reminds me to turn the oven off._

Comment: I think that this needs a bridge-verb to smooth out how this is read. See http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~xtag/tech-report/node93.html

Comment: @StevieV What do you mean by "bridge verb"?  Could you please give an example?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. Is it meant to be issuing a directive? If so, your example would be correct ("someone" + infinitive).

However, if it is stating what happens, then you would have to use "reminds" ("someone" + he/she/it form of "remind") since the pronoun "someone" describes an "it"; an unknown/unspecified person.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  In the "imperative mood" of English language, the infinitive form of the a verb without "to" (in this case "remind") is used.  Normally a subject isn't needed in imperative mood; that's what makes this case a little confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The main clause looks an imperative with a 3rd person subject (someone). Imperatives take the infinitive verb, so "remind" is correct.